# browserify command line use default path other than node_modules

Tags: node.js, browserify, node-modules

I am using browserify to compile my project along with a few dependencies, however I have noticed that for me to able to require a module inside a file without having to declare its path relatively, like `require('mymodule’);` instead of `require(‘./mymodule’)` those must live inside the `node_modules` directory.

Is it somehow possible to add another path to be resolved when checking for these calls through the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable.

It works, for example, with your current path instead of `node_modules` if you run it like this:

```
NODE_PATH=. browserify app.js > bundle.js
```